# Load different Angular app when clicking link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting situation. I need to navigate from one Angular app to a second one when clicking a link.

```
<a href="/otherApp">Other App</a>
```

When I click this link the url updates to `/otherApp`, but the app itself does not load until I refresh the page. I know I'm missing something simple, but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Have you try absolute url ?

Comment: can you explain more? what you want exactly?